# How to clean xcode project and set up everything back

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My iOS app isn't working anymore, and I have no idea what to do anymore.

I removed all **pod** addons, removed `Podfile.lock` made a `pod deintegrate`, made a `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/`, and a `rm -rf /Users/antoinenedelec/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`, and removed my `.xcworkspace` file.

My Podfile contains then:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '13.2'

target 'la soundbox' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # FIRE BASE & GOOGLE AD MOB
  #pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  #pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  #pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  #pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

end
```

Then I make a `pod install`, launched the new `.xcworkspace` file.
I a on deployment Target 13.2 on my target and on my project.

If I compile I have a lot of errors because I have dependencies with those project.
If I add ANY of the pod up there and make a pod install. I have dependencies error, missing package like the following:
`framework not found fblpromises`
`34 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7`
`gRPC-C++ memory error xcode`
`Framework not found "googleutilities"`...

I never have the same error.. Why can't I simply add all the pods, make a `pod update` and run my project ?

I'm totally lost right now.. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit Xcode completely.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Navigate to your Xcode project directory using the cd command.
4. Run the following command to remove the Pods directory and the Podfile.lock file:

`rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`

5. Run the following command to install the pods again:

`pod install`

6. Once the pods have been installed successfully, open your Xcode project again.
7. Go to Product -> Clean Build Folder to clean any cached build artifacts.

After following these steps, your project should be cleaned and you should be able to build it again without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new project, copy all your files with code, except pods. And then init and install your pods again.